# Compare two date fields using SSJS

Tags: xpages, date-comparison, ssjs

I have two date fields in a document.  I need to check if these two fields contain the same value using SSJS.

The values in those fields can either be a datetime or "not set" (empty)

how can I do that?

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to compare the String values of the dates:

```
var d1 = document1.getItemValue("date1").toString();
var d2 = document1.getItemValue("date2").toString();
return d1 == d2
```

When you want to compare only dates, you can do this by converting the date using SimpleDateFormat java class.

```
var sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
var d1 = document1.getItemValueDate("date1");
var d2 = document1.getItemValueDate("date2");
d1 = d1 == null?"":sdf.format(d1);
d2 = d2 == null?"":sdf.format(d2);
return d1.equals(d2)
```

You can adjust the formatting in the first line to comply to your needs.
More info on formatting can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: strangely I could not get that to work. not sure why. My date field sometimes only contain a date, but .toString() seem to return the date + time(now) for both fields, incl the squarebrackets as it is a vector. even though both fields contain the same value it is reporting that it is different. will investigate more

Comment: Thanks. I solved it in another way but you gave me a few ideas. I have actually never used getItemValueDate before which is a Xspdoc property.